# evalute $\int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dy \ dx$ by polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dy \ dx$$

After I sketch the area required, it is a right angle triangle with vertices $(0,0), (3,0), (3,3)$.

Now I have to change it to polar coordinates to solve it. So, I know that $ dA = dx \ dy = r\ dr\ d{\theta}$ by solving the jacobian.

the new integral should be something like $$ \iint_{D*}^{} 1\ dr\ d{\theta}$$ but I am having trouble determining the limits of $r$ and $\theta$.
I think it should be $$0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{4}$$ and $$0\le r\le3.$$ Though I'm not sure about $r$.

Comment: The upper limit on $r$ should be $3\sec\theta$, not $3$.

Comment: When people simply compute a Jacobian in order to deduce that $dx\,dy=r\,dr\,d\theta,$ they miss some of the geometry, which would tell you that in a sense it's really $(dr)(r\,d\theta),$ because $r\,d\theta$ is the infinitesimal length of an arc of a circle. (But for purposes of actually evaluating the integral, it's often better to work with $\int\left(\int \cdots\cdots \, r\, dr\right) d\theta.) \qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum value of $r$ varies with $\theta$. Namely, $r$ is the hypotenuse of the right triangle with vertices $(0,0), (3,0), \left(3, 3\tan\theta\right)$.

Therefore we can calculate the maximum value of $r$ as $\frac{3}{\cos\theta}$.

So the integral is

$$\int_0^{\frac\pi4} \int_0^{\frac3{\cos\theta}} 1\,dr\,d\theta = \int_0^{\frac\pi4}\frac{3\,d\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac32 \ln\left(3+2\sqrt2\right)$$

Comment: Or $3\ln (1+\sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 3):

You're fine but $\;r\;$ is wrong: on the $x$-axis, we have that $0\le r\le 3$, but on the ray $y=x$ we have $0\le r\le 3\sqrt2$ , so we get that $0\le x=r\cos t\le 3\implies 0\le r\le\cfrac 3{\cos t}=3\sec t.$ Try now to complete the answer...

Comment: why did we choose $\frac{\pi}{4}$ as the value for right side to get $3 \sqrt{2}$. I know this sounds like a stupid question but It has been bothering me for a very long time.

Comment: @user108128 Yes, of course. Typo edited and thanks.

Comment: @Thepanda Because the slope of the line $\;y=x\;$ is $\;1=\tan\frac\pi4\;$ , which of course is the tangent of the line with the positive direction of the $\;x\,-$ axis.

Comment: oh! thanks a lot

Comment: My old tutor is here. Nice to see you Don. :-)

Comment: @ResidentDementor Hi there, Res. What've you been up to? Nice to meet you here...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Hi. I've been teaching maths in some Universities and so I have no additional time to spend here as before. Very nice you are back again as before years ago. :-)